# Can I limit the character set when using Zend Pdf?

Tags: php, zend-pdf

I am working with some Asian fonts, which can easily goes beyond 5MB.

You can limit the character-set when embedding a font in Flash, just curious if this is also available in Zend PDF?

Comment: I thought it subsetted the fonts by default, but maybe I'm wrong. If it isn't subsetting by default, perhaps you could use FontForge to manually create a cut down version, although I'm sure that would be quite tedious.

Comment: The resulting file size of around 10MB suggest the entire font has been embedded. Distinct characters are under 100, there is no way it could grow beyond 1MB.

I would try cutting down the font, or simply use a common system font for now...